# How do I restore a Virtualbox VM from backup? (qcow)

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, 16.04, qcow2

I have backed up the contents of the directory "VirtualBox VMs" and now I am trying to restore the states of my virtual machines by copying the backed up files, back.

Now when I select "Machine" -> "Add" and select the `qcow` file of my VM, I receive the following error:

[image: VirtualBox error]

I have tried running

```
vboxmanage internalcommands sethduuid "home/user/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu32-alt-text/ubuntu32-alt-text.qcow"
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
`VBoxManage: error: Cannot set a new UUID: VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED`
```

How do I properly restore a Virtualbox VM?

I'm runnung VirtualBox 5.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 (amd64).

Comment: What version was it made with?

Comment: The same one, 5.0.18. It's actually the same computer with the same installation of VirtualBox; I'm doing a *test run* of backing up and restoring VMs to make sure it works for me.

Comment: How did you back it up?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Nickolai I found the same suggestion and got the same result as you:

`vboxmanage internalcommands sethduuid` gave

```
Cannot set a new UUID: VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

If we're *restoring* a VM, we should first remove the original and its media from inventory.

Select the VM then use `Machine -> Remove` from the menu. After that select `Remove only` option if we want to preserve the original VM's files.

After removing the original, there will be no UUID conflict.  Then we can use `Machine -> Add` and selected the `.vbox` file of the restored VM.